# touch screen and usb not working: any way to remotely control my phone?

Tags: adb, remote-control

I recently had my phone water damaged during my vacation. The phone still boots up but it doesn't respond to any touch input. When connecting to PC, a notification would appear on my PC that the device is not recognized.

So I'm wondering if there's still another way I can remotely control my phone. It is rooted but with ADB function not working because of USB damage, I can't use that feature anymore.  My phone is an Asus zenfone 2, looks like it doesn't have otg. Another option I thought was AirDroid, I can install it from google play. But then I would still need to input my udername and password to run the app.

Help! I just need to recover my data :(

Comment: I would recommend buying an exact model replacement and swapping the motherboards to be able to tap the screen or connect the USB. You'll have to do this anyway to fix the phone. You can sell the remaining parts.

Answer (score 1):

You said that the phone is rooted. Does it has a custom recovery? If you have a custom recovery you can boot to that by using the hardware buttons and you can operate most custom recoveries with the hardware keys. If you are able to do this you can make a Nandroid backup to an external SD card and after that you can extract your data from the Nandroid backup to another phone. I didn't tried yet but with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore&hl=nl, maybe you can extract the data to another phone.

Comment: great idea! The external storage is still working. Actually a few moments after the water damage, it will only just boot up in recovery. A few days later, it would boot in normal mode. But now I can't seem to run it in recovery mode despite the volume down and power buttons still working. I'll keep trying, but I'm running out of options. :(